# Bash array from file

Tags: arrays, bash

So I'm having a text file called myfile that looks like:

```
epochdate1 floatvalue1
epochdate2 floatvalue2
...
epochdaten floatvaluen
```

I was thinking to create an array where I can extract some floatvalues: floatvaluen, floatvalue(n-1), floatvalue(n-100).

How to achieve that? I mean how to declare this array from myfile and how to select the elements?

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mcve].

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Please, also make sure to provide a [mcve].

Comment: "How to achieve that?" – You do it by writing a program which does that. If you have a problem with your program, carefully read the documentation of all the methods, classes, modules, and libraries you are using, write tests for your programs, trace the execution with pen and paper, single-step it in a debugger, then sleep on it, start again from the beginning, sleep on it again, and *then and only then* narrow your problem down to a concise, focused, simple, short, reproducible [mcve] and ask a focused, narrow question on [so].

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array in Bash like this:

```
myarr=($(awk '{print $2}' file.txt))
```

And you'll be able to access its elements like

```
echo ${myarr[0]}
echo ${myarr[10]}
```

Or better yet, declare an associative array:

```
declare -A myarr
eval myarr=($(awk '{print "["$1"]="$2}' file.txt))
```

And you'll be able to access it like

```
echo "${myarr[epochdaten]}"
```

Output: `floatvaluen`

Comment: Or just create an associative array with the epochdates as the keys `)`